# reusing type aliases in type aliases

Tags: f#

So I was quite impressed the other day when I saw...

```
type Foo<'a> = 
   abstract foo : Unit -> 'a
type IsFoo<'a,'b when 'a :> Foo<'b>> = 'a
```

(I know this example is a bit daft)
the point being that complex parametric constraints can be captured in a type alias....nice

I then started using this a bit, but I got to a point where I have a function that requires a Bar

```
type Bar<'b> = 
    abstract bar : Unit -> 'b
```

and so we have

```
type IsBar<'a,'b when 'a :> Bar<'b>> = 'a
```

but then I wanted a Foo that returned a Bar....so I COULD go....(I think)

```
type IsFooThenBar<'a,'b,'c when 'a :> Foo<'b> and 'b :> Bar<'c>> = 
    IsFoo<'a,IsBar<'b,'c>>
```

but this is sort of just a restatement of stuff I already know...really I'd quite like the constraint to be inferred i.e.

```
type IsFooThenBar2<'a,'b,'c> = IsFoo<'a,IsBar<'b,'c>>
```

but that clearly doesnt work because the compiler complains I cant assert IsFoo and IsBar unless I have the required contraints...

any ideas?....I have lots of generic constraints on my code, and these don't really play nicely with type declarations.

to clarify based on some feedback, how can I take a set of type aliases and compose them into more complex ones without simply restating them....i.e. I want to be able to ammend one of the axiomatic aliases, and that be reflectied into derived aliases, without lots and lots and lots of typing.

so making this concrete, I can write

```
let f (x : IsFoo<_,IsBar<_,string>>) = 
    x.foo().bar()
```

which in simple cases is OK...but remember I have lots and lots of parameters...

so I really want to simplify this and write...

```
let f2 (x : IsFooThenBar<_,_,string>) = 
    x.foo().bar()
```

and I can of course do that if I define IsFooThenBar as described above....

i.e. type aliases give me the mechanism I want, but there seems to be no simple way to compose type aliases without restating all the constraints in the top level alias.

thats fine in this case....but for large numbers of parameters, it becomes more and more onerous.

So...an example of a language where you can do this sort of thing is Haskell...

```
> class Foo a b | a -> b where
>     foo :: a -> b
>     
> class Bar a b | a -> b where
>     bar :: a -> b

> class (Foo foo bar,Bar bar a) => FooThenBar foo bar a where
```

I can then use FooThenBar as short hand for saying that there exists functions that map a 'foo to a 'bar and a 'bar to whatever type I specify

(I'm not Haskell expert and had to get help to create this loosely equivalent scenario)

this is the original function

```
> f :: (Bar bar b, Foo foo bar) => foo -> b
> f x = bar (foo x)
```

and this uses the new inferred composition

```
> f' :: (FooThenBar foo bar b) => foo -> b
> f' x = bar (foo x)
```

Comment: Can't it just be `IsFooThenBar<'a, 'b, 'c when 'a :> Foo<'b> and 'b :> Bar<'c>> = 'a`?  That avoids the restatement.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out if you aren't aware, that `<'a when 'a :> X>` can be simplified as `<#X>` (if you don't need a handle to `'a`).  So if you were to have `let f (x:IsFoo<_, Foo<int>>) = ...` you could just write `let f (x:#Foo<int>) = ...`.  And `let f (x:IsFooThenBar<_, Foo<_>, Bar<int>>) = ...` could be `let f (x:#Foo<#Bar<int>>) = ...`

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types

Comment: my examples are trivial...so I'm aware that I can make a complete statement, the point is if have have aliases that capure atomic constraints, can I compose them into more complex ones...without just restating them

Comment: so  "IsFooThenBar<'a, 'b, 'c when 'a :> Foo<'b> and 'b :> Bar<'c>> = 'a" restates the constraint for IFoo and IBar...they are trivial in this example, but if they were complex that would be painful. if IFoo were complex AND I edited, Id then have to edit all these "derived" constaints....thats a lot of typing that will probably go wrong